# No sound in iPhone app after pressing home button

Tags: iphone, ios5, avaudioplayer

My sounds works fine in the simulator, but when I run the app on my phone the sounds stop to work after I press home button and then back into the app. This is in IOS5. How can I solve this? The delegate things for AVAudioPlayer seems to stop too. The app doesn't crash.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
    pathForResource:@"Beep01" ofType:@"wav"];
clickSound =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
clickSound.delegate = self;
[clickSound prepareToPlay];
```

And later I play it with [clickSound play];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure u have

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

in your header.
Then in your AppDelegate you should have this Methods:

```
- (AVAudioPlayer *) getSound: (NSString *) soundName {  
@try {              
    AVAudioPlayer *sound = [[self getDictionary] objectForKey: soundName];      
    if (!sound) {           
        NSError *error;
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: soundName ofType: nil];             
        sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path] 
                                                       error: &error];             
        if (!sound) {
            //NSLog(@"ERROR: Wrong sound format: %@. Description: %@",  soundName,  [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            sound.volume = 0.7;
            //int len = sound.duration;
            [[self getDictionary] setObject: sound forKey: soundName];
            // NSLog(@"%@ loaded, duration: %i sec", soundName, len);
            [sound release];
        }    
    } 
    return sound;
} 
@catch (id theException) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ not found!", soundName);
} 
return nil;

}

- (NSMutableDictionary *) getDictionary {
if (!dictionary) { //Hashtable
    dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
    NSLog(@"new Dictionary");
}
return dictionary;
}
- (void) playSound: (NSString *) soundName {
AVAudioPlayer *sound = [self getSound: soundName];
if (sound) {   
    sound.currentTime = 0;        
    if (!sound.playing) {
        sound.numberOfLoops = 0;
        [sound play];
    }    
} 
}

- (void) stopSound: (NSString *) soundName {
AVAudioPlayer *sound = [self getSound: soundName];
if (sound && sound.playing) {           
    [sound stop];         
} 
}
```

In your AppDelegateDidFinishLaunching you preLoad all Sounds you will use:

```
//pre-Load sounds
[self getSound: @"testSong.wav"];
```

In your - (void)play{} method you have

```
    YourAppDel *appDel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDel playSound:@"testSong.wav"];
```

enjoi

Comment: Thank you. It didn't really fix my problem, but it was an elegant solution. I think it is something that it collides with my AVAudioRecorder that is running at the same time (some kind of VU Meter). So I take this as the solution and will figure out a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When your app goes to the background (or a clock alarm goes off, or the phone receives a call, or the screen locks), your app's audio session is interrupted and your audio player is paused. The recommended way to deal with this interruption is to implement the [AVAudioPlayerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html) methods `– audioPlayerBeginInterruption:` and `-audioPlayerEndInterruption:` in your audio player's delegate. From Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW30):

```
- (void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player {
    if (playing) {
        playing = NO;
        interruptedOnPlayback = YES;
        [self updateUserInterface];
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player {
    if (interruptedOnPlayback) {
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
        playing = YES;
        interruptedOnPlayback = NO;
    }
}
```

Note that when `-audioPlayerEndInterruption:` is called, you send `-prepareToPlay` to your audio player instance again. It's possible that if you don't call that after the interruption, your audio session isn't restarted for you, which would produce exactly the effect you described above—mysteriously dead audio.